# Is it possible to configure sendmail to require/use certain ciphers during TLS negotiation?

Tags: centos, email, smtp, sendmail, tls

CentOS 5.x | SendMail

I'd like sendmail to use a specific cipher when negotiating a TLS session with a specific remote MTA/domain.  Is that possible?

I'm aware that a minimum bit strength can be added to the `TRY_TLS:` parameter in /etc/mail/access but wasn't sure if a cipher could be used here or not.

Comment: Why the down vote? I tried checking Google and prior SF questions before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured this one out:

1) Add the following lines to /etc/mail/sendmail.mc:

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
O CipherList=HIGH:!<CipherNotToUse>
```

2) Restart SendMail:

```
/etc/init.d/sendmail restart
```